# Take part of matrix and augment it

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

The titel might be confusing, but what I am trying to do, is the follwoing:

I have a matrix:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l]
m = {{a, b, c}, {g, h, i}, {d, e, f}, {j, k, l}};
m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

No I wanto to split it into two matrices:

```
m1 = Partition[m, 2][[1]];
m2 = Partition[m, 2][[2]];
m1 // MatrixForm
m2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

and recombine them:

```
Join[m1, m2, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I would like to **automate this**, and *only need to specify the initial matrix* and *the number of partitions*. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: From what I understand, all you have to do with your code is replace every  2 with n, *get rid of taking apart `Partition[m, 2]`* and create a function `myPartition[m_, n_] := Module[{mp},
   mp = Partition[m, n];
   Join[Sequence @@ mp, 2]
   ];`. Note the use of `Sequence@@` to emulate taking a list apart into separate arguments (your `m1`, `m2` etc.) and passing them to a function.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Flatten[]`:

```
Flatten[Partition[{{a, b, c}, {g, h, i}, {d, e, f}, {j, k, l}}, 2], {{2}, {1, 3}}]
 (*  {{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {g, h, i, j, k, l}} *)

Flatten[Partition[{{a, b, c}, {g, h, i}, {d, e, f}, {j, k, l}}, 1], {{2}, {1, 3}}]
 (*  {{a, b, c, g, h, i, d, e, f, j, k, l}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1 = Join[##, 2] & @@ Partition@## &;
f2 = Join @@@ Transpose@Partition@## &;


m = Array[a, {12, 3}];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1[m, 3] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1[m, 4] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1[m, 6] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
And @@ (f1[m, #] == f2[m, #] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 6})
```

> True